# Where to modify a components state before use if needed in React.js apps

Tags: reactjs

I am building a weather app with openweathermap api using React.js.

I fetch the data from the remote server of openweathermap api, however, it is not in the structure I have found easier to work with in rendering my component and its sub-components. Namely, the subpart of data object is a 5 days 3 hourly forecast data in the form of an array of objects, each one is the 3 hourly forecast of 5 successive days. So, this array is not separated into days as each day is also an array of its 3 hourly data is each an object, which I will find easy to render in separate day components.

**My main point is that:**

Where is the best place in a React.js component to modify the state of the component to be used in render and subcomponent renders if necessary, if the structure of the data readily available in state (after a http request to an api or file read) is not best suited to your needs or not in a structure you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch and set the data at `componentDidMount`. Check the official [example](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html). After you set the state here, propagate it to your children as props so everything re-renders.

Comment: thanks, more emphasize in modify in answer would better it.